# jQuery File Upload - Sorting/display images by file id or another kind of selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-file-upload

I need a little assistance with the plugin jQuery File Upload plugin: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/.

I already have the jQFU plugin working in terms of upload files to server and database insertions, but now i can't find how to get the files displayed by id to show then to the user. I always get all the files that are in the dB and in server folder inside the html container. I guess that the problem 'lives' around line 75 in the index.php file, where is the PHP database integration.

I already change value on the `WHERE description=?;` ? but no luck. I need to do something like `WHERE description=$id;` to display only files with id=1 for example.

Here's the original code:

```
protected function set_additional_file_properties($file) {
    parent::set_additional_file_properties($file);
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
        $sql = 'SELECT `id`, `type`, `title`, `description` FROM `'
            .$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `description`=?';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param('s', $file->name);
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result(
            $id,
            $type,
            $title,
            $description
        );
        while ($query->fetch()) {
            $file->id = $id;
            $file->type = $type;
            $file->title = $title;
            $file->description = $description;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be `WHERE id=?` ... since description seems to not be the id... ?

Comment: Already try that... retrieves all the ids in the db id field. The problem is the ? sign. Every time I change it the php freezes...

Comment: You must keep the `?` in there if you are doing a `bind_param`. Change `description = ?` to `id = ?` and then change `$query->bind_param('s', $file->name);` to `$query->bind_param('s', $wherever_you_get_your_id_from);`

Comment: Nope... same result... all files displayed... tks anyway :)